# How to access model inside custom Keras loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
def custom_correlation_loss(input_data, model):
  def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    print(input_data)
    model_prediction = model.predict(input_data)
    print(model_prediction)
    mse_loss = keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred)
    return mse_loss
  return custom_loss

# Some model architecture "model"

model.load_weights('/content/drive/MyDrive/v2a_with_only_sex_combined_10k_model_survey_to_health_outcomes_LSTM.h5', by_name=True, skip_mismatch=True)
model.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = custom_correlation_loss(lambda_x), run_eagerly=True)
```

I actually wanted to compute some information with model inside custom loss function. When I try to access the model. I'm getting "Method requires being in cross-replica context, use get_replica_context().merge_call()"

Can someone let me know what the issue is or How do I access the model inside a custom loss function. So, the model I access is updated after every batch iteration.

RuntimeError: in user code:

```
File "<ipython-input-64-7b5fc945c2b5>", line 102, in custom_loss  *
    x = callback.on_train_batch_end(batch=0, logs={})
File "<ipython-input-42-3132770117f2>", line 42, in on_train_batch_end  *
    y_pred_batch = self.model.predict(x_batch_data.numpy())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler  **
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

RuntimeError: Method requires being in cross-replica context, use get_replica_context().merge_call()
```

Comment: This is VERY strange and you should say "exactly" what you want to achieve, because you cannot use the model while it's already being used. Why do you want to predict from `y_true`? This certainly doens't make sense unless your model is an autoencoder, in which case the results of the prediction are `y_pred`.

Comment: Hi @DanielMöller. THank you so much for your reply. By mistake I have put y_true. Even if I do model.predict(input_data). I get the same error. What I am trying to do is when actually wanted to find the correlation loss w.r.t to the input data i.e. input training batches. Inorder to do that I need model in the custom loss function to calculate. I could directly use y_pred for calculating loss. But the problem is I need to mask the input and get the output prediction value. Please let me know.

Comment: Why do you want this inside the loss? Do it outside.